# GKE : How to get number of nodes and pods using API

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently, I obtaine various information from the GoogleCloudPlatform management console screen, but in the future I would like to obtain it using API.
The information obtained is as follows.

```
Kubernetes Engine>Clusters>Cluster Size
Kubernetes Engine>Workloads>Pods
```

Please teach the API corresponding to each information acquisition.

Comment: REST API or any language specific client library?

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. install your command line
2. connect to your project
3. connect to your cluster
4. retrieve the number of pod inside your cluster

### Install your command line

You can use your prefered command line or you can use the active cloud shell of your browser (the online command line interface integrated to Google Cloud Platform).

Option A) Using your own command line program, you need to install [Google Cloud command (gcloud)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) on your machine.

Option B) Otherwise if you use the active cloud shell, just click on the active cloud shell button on the top of the page.

[image]

### Connect to your project

(only for option A)

- Login to your gcloud platform: ***gcloud auth login***

```
$ gcloud auth login
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=65654645461.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=yJ_pR_9VSHEGFKSDhzpiw&destination=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085&approval_state=!ChRVVHYTE11IxY2FVbTIxb2xhbTk0SBIfczcxb2xyQ3hfSFVXNEJxcmlYbTVkb21pNVlhOF9CWQ%E2%88%99AJDr988AKKKKKky48vyl43SPBJ-gsNQf8w57Djasdasd&oauthgdpr=1&oauthriskyscope=1&xsrfsig=ChkAASDasdmanZsdasdNF9sDcdEftdfECwCAt5Eg5hcHByb3ZhbF9zdGF0ZRILZGVzdGluYXRpb24ASDfsdf1Eg9vYXV0aHJpc2t5c2NvcGU&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

- Connect to your project: ***gcloud config set project your_project_id***

```
$ gcloud projects list

PROJECT_ID              NAME              PROJECT_NUMBER
first-project-265905    My Project        117684542848
second-project-435504   test              895475526863

$ gcloud config set project first-project-265905
```

### Connect to your cluster

Connected to your project, you need to connect to your cluster.

***gcloud container clusters get-credentials your_cluster_name***

```
$ gcloud container clusters list
NAME            LOCATION           MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP     MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VERSION    NUM_NODES  STATUS
test-cluster-1  asia-northeast1-a  1.33.33-gke.24  45.600.23.72  f1-micro      1.13.11-gke.14  3          RUNNING

$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials test-cluster-1
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for test-cluster-1.
```

### Retrieve the number of nodes/pods inside your cluster

inside a given name space run the command

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                          STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
gke-test-cluster-1-default-pool-d85b49-2545   NotReady       24m       v1.13.11-gke.14
gke-test-cluster-1-default-pool-d85b49-2dr0   NotReady       3h        v1.13.11-gke.14
gke-test-cluster-1-default-pool-d85b49-2f31   NotReady       1d        v1.13.11-gke.14

$ kubectl get pods
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox   0/1       Pending   0          44s
nginx     0/1       Pending   0          1m
```

Answer (score 1):

GKE UI under the hood calls Kubernetes API to get information and show in UI.
You can use kubectl to query Kubernetes API to get that information.

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl get pods
```

If you turn on the verbose mode in kubectl then it will show what REST API its calling on the kubernetes api server.

```
kubectl --v=8 get nodes
kubectl --v=8 get pods
```

The REST API for nodes and pods are

```
GET https://kubernetes-api-server-endpoint:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500
GET https://kubernetes-api-server-endpoint:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500
```

Here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) on how to configure Kubectl to connect with GKE.

Here is the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) from kubernetes on different ways to access Kubernetes API.

You can also use [kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#using-kubectl-proxy-1) for trying it out.

Remember to call above rest apis you need to authenticate to kubernetes api server either with a certificate or with a bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about Python, Kubernetes Engine API could be used in this case.

**Kubernetes Engine > Clusters > Cluster Size**

In particular, a  method [get(projectId=None, zone=None, clusterId=None, name=None, x__xgafv=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/container/v1beta1/python/latest/container_v1beta1.projects.zones.clusters.html#get) 
returns an object that contains "`currentNodeCount`" value.

**Kubernetes Engine > Workloads > Pods**

A code example for listing pods could be found here: 
[Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#python-client)

Answer (score 0):

```
gcloud container node-pools describe node-pool-3 --cluster=stg | grep initialNodeCount: | cut -d ':' -f2
```

This solution used just gcloud api for get Count of nodes in GKE.

In this Example you see one line command.

Of describe  specific node-pool "node-pool-3" in  specific cluster "stg"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**